# Use of Dynamic memory allocation in real time system

Tags: memory-management, rtos

I know there is issue in using dynamic memory allocation in real time system. mostly start up time we can use dynamic memory allocation where we don't have to be more deterministic about system response. Can anyone give example where we use dynamic memory allocation for RTS?

e.g loading unknown size of data to ram at run time.

Comment: "Why you want to use dynamic memory?" - This will be first question everyone will shoot at you if you want use Dynamic memory in real time systems.

Comment: let me say you want to load the data from other system which is running independently. As your system doesn't know the exact size from which you are loading you need to allocate dynamically but once at initialization time. I got one example like loading faults those store in non-volatile memory to your RAM/ROM. These faults you need to store the previous state of your system.

Comment: I would still suggest Allocate a pre-defined memory... Read this: http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4008868/Deterministic-dynamic-memory-allocation--fragmentation-in-C--C-